# Please explain this line from the book 'The C Programming Language' Pg 192

Tags: c, token

> *"If the input stream has been separated into tokens up to a given character, the next token is the longest string of characters that could constitute a token."*

Here is what I interpret from this:

Suppose I enter a string `"abc xyz"` ,then there would be two tokens in this input,`"abc"` and `"xyz"`,so `"abc"` is separated from `"xyz"` by white-space and `"xyz"` is the longest string of characters that could constitute a token.

I wish to know if I am understanding this correctly or not?

Comment: Please provide some more context. I don't have that book with me.

Comment: Can anyone help me improving the title of this question?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're basically right, but  the context is different. It is not about the "input", specifically.

The chapter you're referring to, describes the "Lexical Conventions" and tokenizing of the source file(s) during the preprocessing stage.

Just to clarify, To quote the *related* part, from the Chapter "Tokens" in "Lexical Conventions"

> Blanks, horizontal and vertical tabs, newlines, formfeeds and comments as
>   described below (collectively, ``white space'') are ignored except as they separate tokens. Some white space is required to separate otherwise adjacent identifiers, keywords, and constants.
>
> If the input stream has been separated into tokens up to a given character, the next token is the longest string of characters that could constitute a token.

So, it's *not only* the "space" character, the tokens can be separated by any white-space element, as described above. In this case, yes, it is the "space" () character.